# Remover uma class de uma Tag com mais de uma class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estou aprendendo o mundo web, então estou com dificuldades até para verificar se já existem questionamentos parecidos, caso tenha alguma resposta no fórum semelhante, adianto as desculpas. Agora vou a dúvida. (Eu demorei bastante tempo procurando algo, não encontrei.)

Tenho uma TAG com duas `class` em uma tabela.

```
<td class="js-selector-user hide"></td>
```

Quando eu clico em um input `type="radio" class=".js-selector-radio"`, eu preciso remover a class hide.

Eu fiz a jquery dessa maneira:

```
$(function(){
    var selectRadio = $('.js-selector-radio');
    var selecUser   = $('.js-selector-user');

    selectRadio.click(function() {
        selecUser.slideUp('fast', function(){
            selecUser.removeclass('.hide').slidedown('fast');
        }) ;
    });         
});
```

Não remove a class :(

Comment: o seu `removeClass` ta escrito errado, além de não precisar colocar o seletor de classe na hora de removê-la. O correto é: `selecUser.removeClass('hide').slidedown('fast');`,

Comment: Jorge, você esqueceu de tirar o ponto do `.hide`

Comment: Bem observado @fernandosavio. Editado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem basicamente, dois "errinhos", no seu código.

- O `removeclass()` está escrito em minúsculo, ele deve estar dessa forma `removeClass()`.
- O `slidedown()` também está em minúsculo, ele deve estar dessa forma `slideDown()`.

```js
$(function(){
    var selectRadio = $('.js-selector-radio');
    var selectUser = $('.js-selector-user');

    selectRadio.click(function() {
        selectUser.slideUp('fast', function(){
            selectUser.removeClass('hide').slideDown('fast');
        }) ;
    });         
});
```

```css
.hide{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" class="js-selector-radio">

<div class="js-selector-user hide">
    <td> Seu conteúdo </td>
</div>
```

**Obs:** Não sei como está o sua class `hide`, mas provavelmente você deve estar utilizando `display: none;` ou então `visibility: hidden;` para esconder a tag `<td>`. Ambas propriedades não funcionam em uma tag `<td>`. Por isso coloquei as classes na `<div>`

Aqui está um exemplo, mostrando o não funcionamento:

```css
.hide{
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<td class="hide">Teste</td>
```

**Outra Alternativa**

Uma outra alternativa, seria utilizar as próprias funções do **JQuery** para esconder e mostrar os elementos.

```js
$(function(){
    var selectRadio = $('.js-selector-radio');
    var selecUser   = $('.js-selector-user');
    
    selecUser.hide();
    
    selectRadio.click(function() {
        selecUser.slideUp('fast', function(){
            selecUser.show().slideDown('fast');
        }) ;
    });         
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" class="js-selector-radio">

<div class="js-selector-user">
    <td> Seu conteúdo </td>
</div>
```

**Obs:** ela não funciona no `<td>`, então tem que utilizar a `<div>` também.

Answer (score 0):

Você escreveu `removeclass` mas o nome da classe é `removeClass`, com o "c" maiúsculo, além de não precisar colocar o seletor de classe na hora de remover.

O correto é:

```
$(function(){
    var selectRadio = $('.js-selector-radio');
    var selecUser   = $('.js-selector-user');

    selectRadio.click(function() {
        selecUser.slideUp('fast', function(){
            selecUser.removeClass('hide').slidedown('fast');
        }) ;
    });         
});
```